# I need to ignore a specific line while reading a file

Tags: c#

I need to ignore reading the particular line while reading the whole document. 
for example, I have chunk of data and I have read it using    File.ReadAllText(filePath); and I need to ignore reading a particular line, Say 50 and need to read the other lines. So far I have the below code.

```
string fileName = "TextFile.config";
string filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName("TextFile.config") + fileName;
string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

Comment: ReadAllText reads... "all text" without exceptions. You could filter out the unwanted line using ReadAllLines or ReadLines

Comment: What are you doing with `text`? The way you use it has a major impact on the usefulness of any answer.

Comment: If you can describe the condition to us you can code it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ReadLines` and `Where` like here:

```
int[] ignoreLines = { 50 };
IEnumerable<string> relevantLines = File.ReadLines(filePath)
  .Where((line, index) => !ignoreLines.Contains(index + 1));
string resultString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, relevantLines);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `File.ReadAllLines`, this will give you all lines of the file in an array, you can then loop through this array to check for the line you want to ignore (or not ignore), (either with an index or with `string.StartsWith / string.EndsWith`

Answer (score 0):

[File.ReadLines Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Reads the lines of a file.

[List.RemoveAt Method (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Removes the element at the specified index of the List.

[List.RemoveRange Method (Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Removes a range of elements from the List.

**Exmaple**

```
string fileName = "TextFile.config";
string filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName("TextFile.config") + fileName;
var lines = File.ReadLines(filePath).ToList();
lines.RemoveAt(49) // Remove 50th line 
// or
lines.RemoveRange(49,10) // Remove 50th line + 9 more
```

Comment: I have met with the Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: @Priya ok back with you in a sec

Comment: @Priya updated, those method RemoveAt, and RemoveRange, dont return a value, and just modify the list

Comment: My application is getting closed when I added the above code. There was no build error on the code.